# Render Setting for Cycles

Tags: rendering

Plz provide a best render setting. The problem im facing is in Rendered mode the light reflection looks good and and satisfied to click the render button. After rendering taking 1hr it need to give some brightness/contrast in photoshop which i dont want to jump in other software. Any perfect setting which i can match render mode and final render. Im just rendering and image. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give advice without image references.

May be the problem binded with Filmic View which reduces contrast.

There is no "best render setting", different settings are suitable for different situations: architectural or interior visualization, character or product rendering.

To adjust final render you can:

1. Tune Color Management Look, Exposure, Gamma or Use Curves

[image: Tune Color Management Look, Exposure, Gamma or Use Curves]

2. The whole spectrum of Color nodes in Compositor:

[image: spectrum of Color nodes in Compositor]